# How to delete multiple id documents in elasticsearch index

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'ABC',
    log: 'trace',
    apiVersion: '7.1'
});
client.delete({
        index: 'allevents',
        type: '_doc',
        id:"2"
    }).then(function(resp) {
        console.log("Successful query!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 4));
    }, function(err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
```

When I delete a single document by passing single id value.its working fine.

**But I want to delete multiple documents in a single query**.
How will we do?

I tried

```
 client.delete({
    index: 'allevents',
    type: '_doc',
    id: ["2","3"]
})
```

This function returning error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to leverage the [`bulk` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_bulk)/[API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), like this:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'ABC',
    log: 'trace',
    apiVersion: '7.1'
});

var idsToDelete = ["2", "3"];
var bulk = idsToDelete.map(id => {
  return {
     'delete': {
        '_index': 'allevents',
        '_type': '_doc',
        '_id': id
     }
  };
});

client.bulk({
      body: bulk
    }).then(function(resp) {
        console.log("Successful query!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 4));
    }, function(err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
```

Another way of doing it is to leverage the [`deleteByQuery` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_deletebyquery)/[API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html):

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'ABC',
    log: 'trace',
    apiVersion: '7.1'
});

var idsToDelete = ["2", "3"];

client.deleteByQuery({
      index: 'allevents',
      type: '_doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          terms: {
            _id: idsToDelete
          }
        }
      }
    }).then(function(resp) {
        console.log("Successful query!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 4));
    }, function(err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: what can be the maximum limit of "idsToDelete"?

Comment: For which option? the former or the latter?

Comment: In the second option, the `terms` query allows up to 65,536 terms by default (but you can increase that limit by setting `index.max_terms_count` at index creation time). In the first option, the body of the bulk query can be as much as [100MB big](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings) by default (configurable by setting `http.max_content_length`), so you can definitely fit more than 65,536 lines in the bulk body.

Comment: we are passing ids value in an array of " idsToDelete". what will be the maximum value of "idsToDelete" that can be passed for deleted?

Comment: See my earlier comment.